# ASP.NET Core MVC View Models - best practise

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

As far as I'm aware, this isn't a major issue, but I was more curious to see if anyone could offer their expertise regarding some code I'm reviewing. Basically, I've got a view model that is taking a controller class as an argument in its constructor to then store a bunch of properties from the controller class.

I don't want to assert that this is bad practise without being able to explain why, but this isn't a design pattern that I've typically seen when working on MVC web apps, and I'm not convinced it's a great idea to introduce coupling between your view models and your controllers in this way. Is this approach to instantiating your view model okay, or should it be avoided?

Some pseudo code:

```cs
public class SomeController : Controller {
    public SomeController() {

    }

    public Index() {
        var vm = new ViewModel(this);

        return View("Index", vm);
    }
}

public class ViewModel()
{
    public ViewModel(SomeController controller) {

    }
}
```

The closest answer I've found to this is [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/515#issuecomment-366718575), but in this case we're not dealing with dependency injection.

Comment: A ViewModel taking stuff from the Controller is the reversed order - the controller is supposed to make/fill/retrieve (whatever you want to call it) the ViewModel. If your ViewModel is dependant on the Controller in some way, that sounds like a code smell and you should probably investigate why those properties that are needed, are defined on the controller.

Comment: I've certainly never seen this before.  Why on earth does the developer think they need to send the entire controller to the view?  What terrible things are happening in that view?  Basically this comes down to the same question anyone should ask when seeing unexpected code... "Why is this needed?"

Comment: Yeah, I agree with the other comments. The view shoudn't need access to any functionality in the controller and everything the view needs should really be available directly from the View Model. The view shouldn't be concerned with business logic. Would be interesting to see what is being accessed in the controller from the view!

Comment: There isn't anything complicated going on to be honest! This is some refactoring work to make things generic, but there are much nicer ways to achieve this in my opinion. I've suggested either using view components or filter attributes to set commonly used variables across controllers.

Comment: Why not just pass the parameters which are needed instead of the whole controller class in the constructor? If all your view model are constructed as you've shown,what would happen if you modify the name of controllers or move the action from one controller to another?